Error when building Flutter project with fluttertoast: "Could not determine the dependencies of task ':fluttertoast
I'm encountering an issue while building my Flutter project that uses the fluttertoast package. I have updated all my dependencies, and I'm using the latest version of fluttertoast (8.2.8). However, I'm getting the following error:
Warning: SDK processing. This version only understands SDK XML versions up to 3 but an SDK XML file of version 4 was encountered. This can happen if you use versions of Android Studio and the command-line tools that were released at different times.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':fluttertoast:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not determine the dependencies of null.
   > Cannot query the value of this provider because it has no value available.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 11m 30s

I've already tried the following solutions:

Deleted the fluttertoast dependency from pubspec.yaml and ran flutter pub get, but the issue persists.

Removed the android folder and recreated it using flutter create ..

Ensured that I have the appropriate Android SDK installed (I have SDK version 35.0.2).


I am not sure what else to try. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
EDIT:
Mi flutter doctor:

Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.3, on Microsoft Windows [Versi¢n 10.0.22631.4317], locale es-419)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 35.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.11.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 2024.1)
[√] VS Code (version 1.94.2)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] Network resources

• No issues found!
PS C:\UsoftDev\aromacos> flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.3, on Microsoft Windows [Versi¢n 10.0.22631.4317], locale es-419)
    • Flutter version 3.24.3 on channel stable at C:\UsoftDev\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 2663184aa7 (4 weeks ago), 2024-09-11 16:27:48 -0500
    • Engine revision 36335019a8
    • Dart version 3.5.3
    • DevTools version 2.37.3

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 35.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\AlfaNote4\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Platform android-35, build-tools 35.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.11+0--11852314)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.11.3)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
    • Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.11.35303.130
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.22621.0

[√] Android Studio (version 2024.1)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • android-studio-dir = C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.11+0--11852314)

[√] VS Code (version 1.94.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\AlfaNote4\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.98.0

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Versi¢n 10.0.22631.4317]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 129.0.6668.100
    • Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 129.0.2792.79

[√] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.


Can you share your flutter doctor?

HI @Lynxi how are you? I added my flutter doctor

I am facing the same issue, recently
